# Special characters in xaml may kill Intellisense

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, intellisense

[Special characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970677.aspx) makes me intellisenseless.

To reproduce the problem: create new wpf project and change

```
Title="MainWindow"
```

to

```
Title="{Binding Test, FallbackValue=R&amp;R}"
```

Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> - everything looks fine.

But Intellisense is now dead for this xaml. Why? What should I do?

Comment: File a bug report with Microsoft. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/content/content.aspx?ContentID=26698

Answer (score 1):

I cannot duplicate this problem, but I'm using VS2013 with latest updates.

Your options are to check that you have the latest upgrades, then file a bug report as Ron Beyer mentioned.

Otherwise you can also try cleaning and rebuilding the project, or toggling intellisense off, then on again.

Comment: Can you prove it with screenshot? Maybe you did something wrong? Repeat steps (compile) and then e.g. try to add some attribute to `Grid`, do you see Intellisense? I also have VS2013  with all updates, but Express version.

Comment: Just tried an entirely new project (again), still cannot duplicate. The title of the window shows the ampersand fine, and intellisense works correctly before and after both compile and running - both in the Window and Grid elements in XAML, as well as code-behind. I've had intellisense quit momentarily while loading a project, but nothing related to using special characters. Sorry.